# Does NTP server ping time influence the resulting retrieved time

Tags: ntp

I am not entirely sure how delay will skew time syncing with a device. In general when I ping a server such as google I'll have a ~90ms ping. Does this ping  cause the device I am syncing with a NTP server to be off by roughly 90ms or is there some algorithm they use to get around this?

Answer (score 3):

if I understand your question correctly you are trying to understand how the delay between 2 machines over a network is dealt with.

I think section 5.1.2.1 of the [ntp docs](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm) explains what your after.